# MySQL: Sort by single values in different columns

Tags: mysql, sorting

My table looks like this (simplified):

```
name  result1  result2  result3 
A       15     17        24
B       30     31        21
C       27     19        39
```

Now I want to sort the results in columns result1, result2 and result3 so that I get a ranking sorted by the lowest to highest values in these columns.

The results should look like this

```
name  result
A     15
A     17
C     19
B     21
A     24
C     27
B     30
B     31
C     39
```

I don't have any idea how to sort values in different columns with paying attention to every single value and not only the max or min. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you designed this table, please consider normalizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT name,result  FROM
(
SELECT name,  result1 AS result  FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT name,  result2 AS result  FROM YourTable  
UNION ALL
SELECT name,  result3 AS result  FROM YourTable 
) AS T

ORDER BY result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot the data before sorting.  Here is a good way:

```
select name,
       (case when n.n = 1 then result1
             when n.n = 2 then result2
             when n.n = 3 then result3
        end) as result
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
order by result desc;
```

The reason that I prefer this method is for performance reasons.  Using a `cross join` means that the initial table will be scanned only once (as opposed to using `union all` where the table is scanned multiple times).  For a single, smallish table this probably doesn't make a difference.  If the "table" is really a more complex query, the performance difference can be significant.